# How can I define a containing class for another class in python?

Tags: python

I want class B to be like a child of class A:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        b1 = B()
        b2 = B()
        self.games_summary_dicts = [b1, b2]
        """:type : list[B]"""

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def do_something_with_containing_class(self):
        """
        Doing something with self.id of A class. Something like 'self.container.id'
        """
        ...
```

I want 'do_something_with_containing_class' of b1 to actually do something to the instance of A that it's under, so if it changes something, it will also be available for b2.

Is there a class or a syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Natecat has pointed out, give class `B` a member pointing to its `A` parent:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        b1 = B(a=self)  
        b2 = B(a=self)  # now b1, b2 have attribute .a which points to 'parent' A
        self.games_summary_dicts = [b1, b2]
        """:type : list[B]"""

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):  # initialize B instances with 'parent' reference
        self.a = a

    def do_something_with_containing_class(self):
        self.a.id = ...
```

Comment: That worked! I forgot that those objects are passed by reference and not by value, so it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have an instance variable in B that points to its parent instance of A

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class A (object):
def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    b1 = B()
    b2 = B()
    self.games_summary_dicts = [b1, b2]
    """:type : list[B]"""

class B(A):
def __init__(self):
    ...
def do_something_with_containing_class(self):
    """
    Doing something with self.id of A class. Something like 'self.container.id'
    """
    ...
```

Comment: The OP's 'containing' wording is unfortunate. I think he wants access from `b2` to the `A` instance that `b2` is a member of, not actual inheritance.

Comment: Avoid using inheritance if the problem can ce solved with just composition.

Comment: @schwobaseggl you're right. I just don't know how to call it.

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson And inheritance also doesn't work for me - It means that b1 and b2 each have their own self.id and that's not what I want